# Decimation with dynamic factor in GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, decimation

In a GRC flowgraph I have a custom OOT block which periodically sends a PMT message to the "command message port" of the "UHD: USRP Source Block" (for set the RF center frequency
for the two different channel CH A:0 and CH B:0).

I have the problem to dynamically set the sample rate (in different way for the two RX channel):

A constraint of the x310 is that the two RX channel shall have the same sampling rate. So, in order to achieve this goal a Decimation block shall be used (taking in input the UHD Source Block output's).

Is it possibile to set the decimation factor for an existing block or I need to create a custom OOT block my own?

Moreover, in this latter case the usage of a message handler for doing this shall create some issue (thread of the general work will "work" with a global variable set by the "Message Handler" thread).

**Decimator.cc**

[image]

**Decimator.h**

[image]

**Decimator YAML**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possibile to set the decimation factor for an existing block or I need to create a custom OOT block my own?

Yes.

You can adjust the rate of a `keep_one_in_n` block at runtime (`set_n`). It's not an elegant thing, so I'd advise you not to do that.

Interestingly, nobody has yet added a message port handler nor a stream tag handler to `rational_resampler` nor `fir_filter_blk` to make this run-time adjustable.

Now, you could just add a message handler to `fir_filter_blk` that accepts both a new set a of taps (as your decimator will need to have a different bandwidth depending on the decimation) as well as a decimation ratio.

> Moreover, in this latter case the usage of a message handler for doing this shall create some issue (thread of the general work will "work" with a global variable set by the "Message Handler" thread).

No! That's *exactly* what message handlers are designed for: being thread-safe. The message handler gets executed once a single iteration of `work` (or `general_work`) is done, so that no modification happens.

Also, you don't want a *global* variable, you want a member variable of your block class.

Comment: Taking into account your suggestion, I create an OOT block on the basis of the fft_filter_ccc adding a message handler for passing as a PMT dictionary the decimation ratio and the vector<gr_complex> taps. 
When running the grc, containing such OOT block, i see that strange things happen; however i cannot understand where is the problem.

I attach the .cc .h and yaml in order to understand if the problem is within the usage of the 
gr::filter::kernel::fft_filter_ccc(decimation, taps, nthreads) or not.